# Inserting new foreign keys into a new column

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, alter-table

I just added three new columns to `Table A` that I now need to fill with primary keys from Table `TEXT`. For each new cell, I need to create a new `TEXT` record. What is the best way to create a new record and store its primary key for each new field in the table with the new columns?

For example, if `Table A` has 10 records I need to create 30 (10 * 3) new `TEXT` records and insert their IDs into `Table A` so that each of the 30 new cells has a unique `TEXT ID`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    ID INT IDENTITY( 1,1 ) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , Column1 INT NULL
    , Column2 INT NULL
    , Column3 INT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE TEXT
(
    ID INT IDENTITY( 1,1 ) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , [Column] INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO A ( Column1, Column2, Column3 ) 
SELECT 1, 2, 3

INSERT INTO A ( Column1, Column2, Column3 ) 
SELECT 4, 5, 6

INSERT INTO A ( Column1, Column2, Column3 ) 
SELECT 7, 8, 9

select ID, Column1, Column2, Column3
from A

select ID, [Column]
FROM [TEXT]

INSERT INTO TEXT( [Column] )
SELECT TEXTID
FROM 
   (SELECT ID, Column1, Column2, Column3
   FROM A) Tmp
UNPIVOT
   (TEXTID FOR A IN 
      (Column1 , Column2, Column3 )
)AS unpvt
```